# Functional programming with Tidyr's "gather" and Ggplot2 for More Rapid Visual Data Exploration

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

The example code below (*using the happy dataset from productplots or ggmosaic*) lets me quickly visualize various categorical variables (sex, marital, health, and degree)broken down by happiness (happy). To accomplish this, I have to separate out the variable I want to condition on from the "gather" function, in this case, "happy". But what if I want to change this variable? Or create another combination? I'll have to continually reproduce the code below and change the variables. Is there a faster way to accomplish this with a function? Can the purrr package help in some way?

```
Df1<-happy%>%
select(sex, happy, marital, health, degree)%>%
gather(key, value, -happy)%>%
count(happy, key, value)%>%
na.omit()%>%
mutate(perc=round(n/sum(n),2))

P<-ggplot(H5)+geom_col(aes(x=value,y=perc,fill=happy))+facet_wrap     
(~key,scales="free")+geom_text(aes
(x=value,y=perc,label=perc,group=happy),position=position_stack(vjust=.05))
```

I would like a solution(s) based on the Tidyverse as much as possible.

Comment: Could you add some code for a sample plot as you are re-typing every time? Most likely it can be craftted into a function wich takes only the column names as arguments.

Comment: I added some code and tried to better articulate my thoughts, hopefully it's more clear and you can help me find the solution I'm looking for!

Comment: I tried to make it even clearer...

Comment: How about actually reproducible vs clearer (including `library()` calls) and SO doesn't charge extra for space or indentation, either.

Comment: Make a function and read https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are looking at the same set of columns, you can wrap this in a function by converting to the standard evaluation versions of each of the functions you use. Here is your same code, just tweaked to run in a function:

```
plotLook <- function(thisCol = "happy"){
  happy %>%
    select(sex, happy, marital, health, degree) %>%
    gather_("key", "value"
            , names(.)[names(.) != thisCol]
            )%>%
    count_(c(thisCol, "key", "value")) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    mutate(perc=round(n/sum(n),2)) %>%
    ggplot() + 
    geom_col(aes_string(x="value",y="perc",fill=thisCol)) +
    facet_wrap(~key,scales="free") +
    geom_text(aes_string(x="value",y="perc"
                         ,label="perc",group= thisCol)
              ,position=position_stack(vjust=.05))
}
```

Now this:

```
plotLook("sex")
```

generates:

[image]

Even better, you can then use `lapply` to generate all of the plots in one go:

```
lapply(c("sex", "happy", "marital", "health", "degree"), plotLook)
```

and either save the output to use/modify, or just let them print to the screen.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's exactly what I was looking for and it works awesome, especially the final "lapply" call. I've been reading up on standard evaluation, but I just have one quick question about your code. Why does the "count_" call require the vectorized "c"? Is it because this is a grouped function that requires a specific order?

Comment: Instead of taking an unlimited number of column specifications using `...` like `count` uses, `count_` requires a single argument `vars` that contains a character vector with all of the desired column specifications. Therefore, to get the grouping by all three columns as desired, you need to combine them into a single character vector.